# Write double precision binary files using python

Tags: python, double-precision

How can I write double precision files binary files using Python? I am doing the following presently but it is giving me single precision files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import struct

data =[2.3715231753176,9.342983274982732]

output_file = "test.dat"
out_file = open(output_file,"wb")
s = struct.pack('f'*len(data), *data)
out_file.write(s)
out_file.close()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `d` to write double precision floats:

```
s = struct.pack('d'*len(data), *data)
```

`f` is *single* precision only. See the [Format characters](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) section of the `struct` module documentation:

> For the `'f'` and `'d'` conversion codes, the packed representation uses the IEEE 754 binary32 (for `'f'`) or binary64 (for `'d'`) format, regardless of the floating-point format used by the platform.

Comment: This works great. However what I was looking for was a fast way to write out binary data and read it back in to another python script at a later point in time. Using numpy.save()  and numpy.load() makes this very easy. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html

Comment: @poleguy: it may make it easy but that's one specific format and a hefty library dependency. Note that the question here specifically asked about using `struct.pack()`, and the issue was not binary data writing in general, but writing floating point values.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the format string wrongly. To use double precision, use 'd' instead of 'f'. See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) for a list of format characters.